# is variable capture in lambda functions which are members of a static data structure allowed?

Tags: c++

I got the following code snipped.

```
bool parseTool() {
   string name;
   string version;
   static /*!!*/ AttrMap attrMap = {
       {"name", Attr([&](const string &val)->bool{name = val;return true;})},
       {"version", Attr([&](const string &val)->bool{version = val;return true;})},
   };
   return parseAttributes(attrMap);
}
```

The attrMap is declared static and lambda functions capture variables from the stack of the parseTool.

Compilation produces no errors and executable runs happily, up to some point, when it starts producing trash.  Of course, removing 'static' fixes the 'trash' issue (probably making name and version static will fix it too, but i have not tried it). I do not understand what does compiler capture in this case when the static `attrMap`  is initialized.

The question is, why did not compiler complain about it? Is there anything in the standard which would mark this case (I could not find one)? What does compiler do there?

I was running gcc-7.2.8 with -std=c++17 on linux.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is `/*!!*/`?

Comment: It captures references to current `name` and `version` variables when the function is called the very first time. And yes making those variables `static` would also "fix" the problem. And have you tried enabling more warnings, with flags such as `-Wall` or `-Wextra` or even `-Wpedantic`?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. static objects are specified as being initialized the first time execution enters the scope. So the lambda captures them by reference. And as soon as the function returns, the referenced objects are destroyed. The next time execution enters this scope it will execute the lambda with invalid references. The lambda using those references triggers undefined behavior. This is "allowed" only in the sense that the shown code is not ill-formed. But just because a program is not ill-formed, that is not a guarantee against UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It looks like a marker comment for something weird...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm pretty sure it's just a note pointing to the important part.

Comment: There's a number of layers between the lambda and the static variable that'd likely make compiler detection hard or impossible. Its capturing local variables (which is very common), used to construct an `Attr` (a user defined type) which the compiler may or may not know persists the lambda (probably through an intermediate type), and then to an `attrMap` (another user-defined type?) which the compiler may or may not know persists the elements.

Comment: What is this code supposed to accomplish? I understand it may be abridged, but `attrMap` has no direct knowledge of `name` and `version`, so the return statement does not reference those variables. What does modifying the otherwise unused local variables in those lambdas achieve?

Comment: If you are asking 'why compiler didn't detect X' you need to show X. Right now the code is not compilable.

Comment: We cannot know why the compiler did not complain without a declaration of `Attr` and the definition of its constructor. The lambda is inappropriate for use in a static data structure. However, it is not used in the static data structure; it is used to construct an `Attr` object. If, for example, the `Attr` constructor ignores the lambda, then there would be no problem. Hence the need to see definitions.

Comment: @MaxLanghof -- yes, it is abridged. Was just a way for structured walking an xml dom document with callbacks as lambda functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- yes, it ran with -Wall. I tried other 2 as well, no warnings about this issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is a [chess anotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_annotation_symbols) and means the move is excellent. Or maybe it's the developper equivalent of _(sic!)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing that the references you are capturing will no longer be valid the next time the lambda is called or even if the lamda will ever be called again.

The code you have posted is dangerous and likely to fail but is perfectly valid according to the standard so the compiler is free to accept it without warnings.

To fix it capture the variables by value or make the lambda not static. Making the lambda static probably doesn't make much sense as creating a lambda probably isn't expensive in most implementations and depending how the lambda is used may be inlined away completely.

Comment: *"is perfectly valid according to the standard so the compiler should accept it without warnings."*: Compilers might **warn** for valid codes (and they do).

Comment: the problem is, that this issues is tough to debug. Fixing is easy, spotting it without a compiler help is difficult.

Comment: *"likely to fail but is perfectly valid"* semantically, sure. But its only the behavior is only well *defined* on the first call, when version and name are still alive. All subsequent calls would exhibit undefined behavior due to use of dangling references.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x yes but the compiler has no way of knowing there will be subsequent calls. `std::string& f() { std::string a; return a; }` will never work so the compiler can issue a warning, the OPs code will work once so the compiler doesn't warn.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Their point was not that the compiler should warn but that the code is not "perfectly valid" in the common sense. If the snippet included two calls to `parseTool`, it would be demonstrably violating the standard. The asker's statements imply that this is the case.

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, there are multiple calls and from different callers.